# How do I ignore a regex match if a line has a special prefix?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm using this regex in Perl to match and replace the following expressions:

- `_HI2_`
- `_HI_2`
- `HI2_`
- `_HI_2`

  ```
  if ($subject =~ m/_?HI2?_?|HI2?_?/) {
      # Successful match
  } else {
      # Match attempt failed
  }
  ```

I also want to do this though:

```
The text is:   ABCDEMAFGHIJ
```

This is a sequence `HI` in there but must be ignored because if you look left you can see that this line starts with `The text is:`.

```
The text is:   ABCDEHI2FGHI
```

As above, two sequence of `HI` here.

How can I build into this regex a match and ignore it because of a line prefix?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just match twice?
If $subject does not match /^The text is:/, run the replace ..

Comment: Just use an if(){}else{}.

Suggest you try reading something.. "modern perl" maybe? It's free as a pdf here: http://onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
/^(?!The text is:).*(?:_?HI2?_?|HI2?_?)/
```

Or use two matches like:

```
if($subject !~ /^This text is:/i && $subject =~ /_?HI2?_?|HI2?_?/)
```

Comment: using example 1:

AAA_HI2_BBB_CCC <--- This one seems to be the only one that gets picked up, and it's also picking up the AAA_ before the HI2_
AAA_HI_2_BBB_CCC
The text is:  ABCDEMAFGHIJ
The text is: ABCDEHI2FGHI

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered this brilliant resource [here](https://legacy.gitbook.com/book/learnbyexample/command-line-text-processing/details) and the section on [Perl](https://learnbyexample.gitbooks.io/command-line-text-processing/content/perl_the_swiss_knife.html).

You can find there details of a `(*SKIP)(*F)` construct which will blow your mind; your described problem as a one-liner:

```
cat > test.txt <<EOF
_HI2_
_HI_2xxxHI_2
The text is:   ABCDEMAFGHIJ
HI2_
The text is:   ABCDEHI2FGHI
_HI_2
EOF

perl -ne '/^The text is:.*$(*SKIP)(*F)|.+/ && s/_?HI_?2?_?/HAPPY/; print' test.txt

# or

perl -ne 's/(^The text is:.*$)(*SKIP)(*F)|_?HI_?2?_?/HAPPY/g; print' test.txt
```

I have new found love and respect for Perl; Sed is my go-to, but now I know how to skip lines (read: leave unchanged) in Perl, I will hesitate less

Answer (score 0):

Try telling it is the start of the line with "^", ignore whitespaces if that you think is needed(I always tend to do it). Also you could mark the end of the string with "$"

```
if ($subject =~ m/^\s*_?HI2?_?|HI2?_?/) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant method but easy to understand (TIMTOWTDI :)

```pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;


my @text = ("ABCDEHI2FGHI", "The text is:   ABCDEHI2FGHI");

for (@text) {
    my $new = my_replace($_); # do the replacement
    print "$new\n";           # print result
}

sub my_replace {
    my ($text) = @_;
    return $text if ($text =~ m/The text is:/);      # return if prefixed / no replacement
    $text =~ s/(_?HI2?_?|HI2?_?)/__replacement__/g;  # do replace (give a replacement string here)
    return $text;                                    # return result of replacement
}
```

Otherwise you can use a "**negative lookbehind**".

To try see [regex101](https://regex101.com/) or [debuggex](https://debuggex.com).

Answer (score -1):

`/(?<!^The text is.*)(_?HI2?_?|HI2?_?)/`

Comment: Lookbehinds can only be fixed length

Comment: hmmm, the lines with HI in with "The text is" at the start of them still seem to be getting picked up?

Comment: would it be better to just let the perl code do it?`if ($subject =~ m/The text is/) {
 # ignore the line, move onto the next line? -- what would the perl code be to do that?
} else {
 # Match attempt failed
}`